# PowerShell : How to show a Help message (Syntax) instead of an error when no parameters specified

Tags: powershell, syntax, parameters

I wrote a script to retrieve VM metrics from VMware vCenter.
A user needs to provide 2 arguments/parameters.
One is the vCenter server and the other is one of the following :
Single VM name  **or**  a file containing a list of VMs.

All of this works fine, but if someone tries to run this script at the PS console without providing any arguments, it throws an exception. (shown below)
Questions :
1) Is the exception pointing to an issue I don't know ?
2) I would rather, the user be shown the Syntax instead of an exception. Is that possible ?

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param (
    [Parameter( Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName ='List' )]
    [Parameter( Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName ='OneVM' )]
    [string]$vCenterServer,

    [Parameter( Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName ='List' )]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [ValidateScript( { Test-Path -LiteralPath $_ -Type Leaf })]
    [string]$vmListFile,

    [Parameter( Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName ='OneVM' )]
    [string]$MyVM
)
```

When I run this without providing arguments/parameters, here is what I see.

```
PS> c:\Temp\vCenter_RT_PerfData.ps1
C:\Temp\vCenter_RT_PerfData.ps1 : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [vCenter_RT_PerfData.ps1], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,vCenter_RT_PerfData.ps1
```

Here is what I wish they would see.

```
SYNTAX
    C:\Temp\vCenter_RT_PerfData.ps1 -vCenterServer <String> -MyVM <String> [<CommonParameters>]

    C:\Temp\vCenter_RT_PerfData.ps1 -vCenterServer <String> -vmListFile <String> [<CommonParameters>]
```

Any suggestions on presenting this another/better way are also welcome.

Answer (score 0):

From this link: [PS Microsoft](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/hey-scripting-guy-how-do-i-add-help-information-for-windows-powershell-parameters/) we can see:

```
<#
    .SYNOPSIS
      Displays a list of WMI Classes based upon a search criteria
    .EXAMPLE
     Get-WmiClasses -class disk -ns rootcimv2″
     This command finds wmi classes that contain the word disk. The
     classes returned are from the rootcimv2 namespace.
#>
  If($local:paramMissing)
    {
      throw “USAGE: getwmi2 -class <class type> -ns <wmi namespace>”
    } #$local:paramMissing
```

Hope this helps.